# How can I make opening files in root inaccessible?

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

Recently I've bought a VPS and I've uploaded my website *(all files and folders)* on it. Now there is a security problem. Everyone can simply see all files on the directory. I mean if the user write my domain name in his browser and press enter, he will see a list of all files on the root of directory. *(I use Laravel and there isn't any `index.php` (or `.html`) file at root)*

Anyway, based on some search, I figured out I have to use some code in `.htaccess` file to make all branch of directory inaccessible. Does anybody know how can I do that?

Comment: You need to precent directory listing - http://viralpatel.net/blogs/htaccess-directory-listing-enable-disable-allow-deny-prevent-htaccess-directory-listing/

Comment: One way is to password protect directory via .htaccess.